# On finding the zeros of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

What is the zero (real) of the polynomial $$x^{k+1}-2x^{k}+1=0$$
If there is such, how can I find it or what method can I use?

Comment: $x=1$ for sure would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: Except for very special cases $(k=1,2,3)$, and beside the trivial case $x=1$, I think that only numerical solutions could be available.

Comment: @imranfat yes ... i forgot to say aside from 1. tHANKS

Comment: $x < \sqrt{2}\qquad$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{k+1}-2x^k+1$.
For $k=1$ the polynomial is just $(x-1)^2$ and has $1$ as double root. 
For $k=2$ we find that $f(x)=(x-1)(x^2-x-1)$ has roots $1$ and $\frac{1\pm\sqrt 5}{2}$.
So now assume $k\ge3$.
From $$\tag1f(x)=x^{k+1}-2x^k+1 =(x-1)(x^k-x^{k-1}-x^{k-2}-\ldots-1)$$
we see that - again - one simple root is at $x=1$. 
For $x\ge2$ we have
$$\tag2 f(x)=x^{k-1}((x-1)^2-1)+1\ge 1$$
and for $x\le-1$ we have $|f(x)|=|x^{k-1}((x-1)^2-1)+1|\ge |x^{k-1}((x-1)^2-1)|-1\ge 2$, hence all real roots are in the interval$(-1,2)$.
For $1-\sqrt 2\le x<1$, we see from $(2)$ that $$|f(x)-1|\le|(x-1)^2-1|<1,$$
hence there are no roots in $[1-\sqrt 2,1)$.

The second factor in $(1)$ is $=1-k<0$ at $x=1$, hence $f(1+h)<0$ for small positive $h$, hence there is (at least) another root in $(1,2)$, which is best found numerically.
If $k$ is even, $f(-1)=-2<0<1=f(0)$ shows that a third real root must be in $(-1,0)$, also best found by numerical methods.

We have 
$$ f'(x) = (k+1)x^k-2kx^{k-1} = ((k+1)x-2k)x^{k-1}$$
which has a $(k-1)$fold root at $0$ and a simple root at $\frac{2k}{k+1}=2-\frac2{k+1}$. Since between any two roots of $f$ there must be at least one root of $f'$, we conclude that

- There is only one root of $f$ in $(1,2)$ and it must be in $(2-\frac2{k+2},2)$
- There is at most one root of $f$ in $(-\infty,0)$.

Hence for $k$ even there are exactly three real roots, one in $(-1,1-\sqrt 2)$, one at $1$ and one in $(2-\frac2{k+2},2)$.
And for $k$ odd there are exactly two real roots, one at $1$ and one in $(2-\frac2{k+2},2)$.

Comment: many thanks, this was the answer that i was looking for

Comment: @JRMA:  It is fair to ask - What is your motivation for this inquiry?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing you can observe is that $x=1$ is a zero, as is always the case when the coefficients add up to $0.$ At that point, you could use polynomial long division or synthetic division to factor.

Alternately, note that the factorization is easy for $k=0$ and $k=1,$ and for $k\ge 2$ we have $$\begin{align}x^{k+1}-2x^k+1 &= x^{k+1}-x^k-x^k+1\\ &= x^k(x-1)-(x^k-1)\\ &= x^k(x-1)-(x-1)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}x^j\\ &= (x-1)\left(x^k-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}x^j\right).\end{align}$$

Sadly, finding the zero(es) (aside from $x=1$) of this polynomial will be impossible to determine in general for sufficiently large $k.$ It's easy for $k=2,$ but after that, it quickly goes from [tedious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_formula#Cardano.27s_method) to [impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel-Ruffini_theorem) to determine analytically (the best we're likely to be able to do for most $k$ is find numerical approximations).

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I don't have better news for you! Were there any steps that I used here that you didn't understand?

Comment: all is clear cameron, thanks again