# Generic solution of a specific polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials

I am trying to find out if there is a generic solution(s) for x in terms of n for the following polynomial equation.

$$
x^{n} = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1}x^p
$$

I tried to do google search for similar form but nothing came out of the search. Wondering if there is such a form?

Comment: @Moo They would be equal at the $n$ roots of the polynomial $x^n - x^{n-1} - \dots - x - 1$.

Comment: There is no closed form, see [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113303/closed-form-of-the-real-zeros-of-xn1-2xn1-for-positive-integer-n), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648909/on-finding-the-zeros-of-a-polynomial) found  by [approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/).

Comment: Thanks @dxiv I also found this gem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207962/can-the-roots-to-the-polynomial-x6-x5-x4-x3-x2-x-1-be-found-i?rq=1.